# Migrate Old VS 2015 .suo file to the New VS 2022 DocumentLayout.json

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2022

Good Day!

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Devsense PHP Tools to develop PHP projects and I have dozens of huge PHP projects and each project has dozens of opened documents and distributed over 3 monitors, Now after upgraded to the Visual Studio 2022, I lost all opened documents stored in the old .suo file.

I noticed that Visual Studio 2022 has a new method to store the opened documents in a **DocumentLayout.json** file rather than the old .suo file and it didn't migrate it to the new version.

Am I the only person who lost his opened documents because of migrating from old Visual Studio? Should I use virtual machine to open every single project to see the opened documents and the last scene of each project? or there's a tool to migrate the old .suo to the new .json file?

Any Thoughts?

Comment: if you opened your solution in vs2022 and it didn't work, then you're doomed.

Comment: Do you know it's related to Devsense PHP Tools or VS 2022 itself?

Comment: I am just sure that things have changed so much since 2015 that VS2022 would just ignore and start over.